# Could I get a out of memory error in this situation?

Tags: java, string, memory-management, out-of-memory, string-interning

So in Java, Strings are interned into a pool meaning they are stored in memory automatically.
In that case if I do something like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2000000000; i++){
     System.out.print(i + "somelongstring");
}
```

Could I run out if memory?
I say this because 2 billion different strings are being made and stored in memory.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: No. Because you have a logical error in your condition `i == 2000000000;` must be `i <= 2000000000;`

Comment: No, because not every string is interned (even though they are stored in memory - where else should they be stored?). After printing each one of your strings is no longer referenced and is therefore garbage collected

Comment: Oops <= 
@Thomas I see, I suppose thats because they are interned using Weak references?

Comment: No, strings are interned either because they are string constants or because someone called `String.intern()` on the instance. All other string instances are normal objects that can (and will) be garbage collected.

Comment: @Thomas that was the exact answer i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: …and even if they were interned, they could still get garbage collected.